# I want to remotely connect to my computer

Tags: openvpn, port-forwarding, remote-access, wide-area-network

I am using Reliance 4G mobile internet (i connect through mobile wifi hotspot to pc), my mobile has been assigned a ip of 10.x.x.x network (private) and , when i use hotspot my pc is assigned ip in network of 192.168.x.x , Now I want that I,or somebody else.. can remotely connect to my pc, (This was easy while using Landline Broadband connection with help of port forwarding technique,) Now as i cannot port forward, Is there any way to accomplish this task. I googled a lot, there I found solution,... to use VPN, so i configured OpenVPN on my linux machine.. VPN Connection was successful (I used free vpn service and trial vpn services) and my public ip was also changed.. but still I cannot forward any port or cannot access my system through internet. Please provide me a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't port forward then a direct connection from external to your machine will not work, period.

Additionally, many 3G/4G connections don't allow inbound connections and (by design) do not allow user configuration of such things as port forwarding.

You should look into the solutions that use a client to make an outbound connection to an external server/service such as TeamViewer.

TeamViewer: Client_1 is your computer. Client_2 is your friend's computer.

```
[Client_1] <==> [TeamViewer servers] <==> [Client_2]
```

Both clients connect to the server (usually using HTTPS port 443) which overcomes port forwarding problem.

The TeamViewer servers act as a connection negotiation/broker so that you can connect to the right remote user (the ID and PIN) and complete the connection.